# Discrete Math - Show Logically $X$ beat $Y$ exactly 2 Times

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I was given a statement that I need to show logically. The question is #6 on [this page](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~irani/f13-6B/homework/week2). I have figured out the other 3 on my own but am stuck on this part of question:

> Define the predicate $B(x, y)$ to mean that $x$ beat $y$ in the race. Give the logical expression equivalent to 'Sam beat exactly two people'.

I know that the use of a universal or existential quantifier is most likely required here but I am not sure how to write the expression "equal to two" in conjunction with them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what sort of language you are using for your class, but you might let  $P$ be the set of all people. Claim that $B(\text{Sam},p_i)$ is true for some $p_i \in P$ with $i=1,2$, and $p_1 \neq p_2$. If $B(\text{Sam}, p)$ is true then either $p = p_1$ or $p = p_2$.

Comment: That does make sense and that is language that we're using in class. Would this fulfill the statement that he beat exactly two people though? Your last statement saying $y=y1$ or $y=y2$ makes me believe that he only beat one or the other. Unless I'm interpreting it incorrectly.

Comment: That statement is a safe catch to say "If $B(\text{Sam},p)$ is true for what appears to be a third person $p$, then really $p$ was just $p_1$ or $p_2$ in disguise." That along with the distinction that $p_1 \neq p_2$ gets you exactly two people beaten by Sam.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense! Thanks for your explanation, helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You want to say that there exist people $x$ and $y$ such that:

- Sam beat $x$;
- Sam beat $y$;
- $x$ and $y$ are not the same person; and
- for any person $z$, if Sam beat $z$, then $z$ is $x$ or $z$ is $y$.

Comment: I understand that portion of it. But how can I express that Sam beat, out of the pool of $y$ people, exactly two of them

Comment: @Bob: That follows from the conditions that I listed: the first three guarantee that Sam beats at least two people, and the fourth guarantees that he beats at most two.